Why did Chani only say "Usul" here instead of "Muad'Dib Usul"?
Stilgar gives Paul the name Muad'Dib Usul, and everyone starts hugging
him and whispering "Muad'Dib Usul" in his ear, but Chani hugs him and
simply says "Usul".
Why did Chani only say "Usul" here instead of "Muad'Dib Usul"?

This isn't a bad question within the context of the string of terrible questions you've been asking, so in all fairness, have a +1.

The Fremen have multiple "names" depending on circumstances.
They have a secret name amongst themselves given by others, here Paul is "Usul".

[Stilgar] You shall be known among us as Usul.

But they also have war names which the bearer must choose, and Paul is known as "Muad’Dib."

[Stilgar] Usul. And now, a Fedaykin is a fighter and needs a war name. You must choose.

So, when they are alone together in private, Chani uses their private name, Usul. When in battle or in public with non-Fremen around, Maud'Dib would be used.

According to the book, "Muad'dib", meaning "kangaroo mouse", is the name given to Paul Atreides for use among the Fremen at large, while "Usul", meaning "Base of the Pillar", is a secret name known exclusively to the members of Sietch Tabr.  Thus, calling him "Usul" is far more intimate, and thus more appropriate for a romantic relationship.

In fact, in the book Paul receives both names and all the Fremen present embrace him and call him "Usul" - Chani did, Stilgar did, and all the others did.  There wasn't a difference between the greeting Chani gave him and the greeting the others gave him.  So the screenwriter and director made this change for the film.  I don't know why they did, but my guess is exactly what you describe here:  Establishing a difference in intimacy between how everyone in Sietch Tabr accepts Paul and how Chani accepts him.
